# Is there a way to automatically display a sum from a google spreadsheet on a webpage?

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I'm using google charts and using a jquery to grab data from a google spreadsheet. It's allowing me to have the charts update as I add more data (in this case a listing of individual donations) in the google spreadsheet. Is there a way to display the sum of the donations in the webpage?

My chart is located here:
https://www.ramirezforcouncil.com/transparency

My public google spreadsheet is located here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m9YfmVp1PbaMe6Cl-KhfFMGNJcEEMfgOvczgqojizPw/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [query language reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) to know how to query from spreadsheets.

Use query like `Select SUM(H)`
So your final URL will be like

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m9YfmVp1PbaMe6Cl-KhfFMGNJcEEMfgOvczgqojizPw/gviz/tq?tq=select+sum(H)
```

If using visualization JS, it is even easier to use the query.
Check this 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#gid

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I'm missing some basics here since I mostly copied and pasted things I didn't completely understand to make this work. What do I do with the URL? Do I need to copy my existing the j query code and just insert it?